# Is it possible to virtually divide hadoop cluster into small clusters

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop-partitioning

We are working to build a big cluster of 100 nodes with 300 TB storage. Then we have to serve it to different users (clients) with restricted resources limit i.e., we do not want to expose complete cluster to each user. Is it possible ? If it is not possible then what are other ways to do it. Are there any builtin solutions available ? It is just like cluster partitioning on demand.

Comment: You only have 3TB average of storage on each node? You realize each data node can use more than one hard drive, right? And 4TB+ disks are preferred for this type of storage? I work on a cluster of 100 nodes as well, but it has 5 PB of storage

Comment: Are you referring to dividing HDFS data or computing resources?

Comment: Computing resources

Answer (score 0):

On hadoop 2 there is a concept of [HDFS Federation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Federation.html) that can partition the file system namespace over multiple separated namenodes each of which manages a portion of the file system namespace.